# Conditional Formatting exact text match

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have several spreadsheets where I want to highlight all the rows where the data matches a separate list. I have used a rule for this but it's not highlighting it exactly; it's just matching part of the word, for example `General manager` in one list is highlighting `Manager` in the other list whereas I would only want it to highlight `General manager`.

This is the formula I've used:

```
=COUNTIF(A92:A400,L2:L196)
```

and I've also tried MATCH but it pulled out out even more incorrect matches.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bring in the [EXACT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EXACT-function-243E2BC1-93D6-4FD5-9608-DC3C5B8C046B) somewhere.

[image: exact_CF]

This CF rule was created by selecting A1:D7 and creating a rule based upon the following formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:1)/EXACT($A1, $F$8:$F$10), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't use excel much, what do the numbers in the aggregate and row do, I tired to apply this rule and change it for the data I wanted but it just highlighted everything!

Comment: (see [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)) The type of formula or even the function used is not that important. You just need to have some way to introduce EXACT into the equation with cyclic calculation. `=EXACT($A1, $F$8:$F$10)` wasn't working so I wrote the first one I could think if and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret the question is that case sensitivity may not be required, rather that use of wildcards may be causing issues (ie that *exact text match* is not applying "exact" in quite the same way the EXACT function does). If the separate list is the one in ColumnL then please select from A92 to A400 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(L$2:L$196,A92)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of highlighting, OK, OK.

If to be applied to several sheets it may be convenient to Name the L2:L196 range.

The above highlights cells rather than rows, but that could be adjusted.